# JavaScript Grading Scale Calculating error with multiple wrong answers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to code so my mistake is probably obvious but, 
When I go and test the calculator, it reads "A" then where ever the proper grade should be then Undefined. Idk where I'm going wrong.
I've tried a lot of different variations, and can't get the calculator to work properly. I'm not sure where the problem is.

```
function calculateGrade(grade) {if (parseInt >= "90"){
   alert ("A");
}
else if (parseInt >= "80" === parseInt < "90"){
   alert ("B");
}
else (parseInt >= "70" === parseInt < "80");{
   alert ("C");
}
if (parseInt >= "60" === parseInt < "70"){
   alert ("D");
}
else if (parseInt < "60"){
   alert ("F");
}}
var inputGrade = prompt("Enter a grade:");
var parsedInt = parseInt(inputGrade);
var finalGrade = calculateGrade(parsedInt);
alert(finalGrade);
```

Comment: parseInt is a function, not a magic variable that knows what you are thinking - did you mean parsedInt? also ... you go to the trouble of parsing an integer, then compare it with a string?

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I will go back and now I know where to look. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions and errors in your code

1. You already have parsed into `number`, so leave the `'90'` quotes from the numbers.
2. Don't use magic names and global variables. Your function accepts the `grade` argument. Use it in your code.
3. Your `if else` conditions are wrong. Some of them are without `else if`. You can left the second part of each `else if` conditions.
4. Return the `final` which you expect from the function.

```js
function calculateGrade(grade) {
   let final = '';
   
   if (grade >= 90) {
       final = 'A';
   } else if (grade >= 80) {
       final = 'B';
   } else if (grade >= 70) {
       final = 'C';
   } else if (grade >= 60) {
       final = 'D';
   } else {
       final = 'F';
   }
   
   return final;
}

let inputGrade = prompt("Enter a grade:");
let parsedInt = Number.parseInt(inputGrade);
let finalGrade = calculateGrade(parsedInt);
alert(finalGrade);
```

Comment: It would read greater than or equal to 80 and less than 90...Right?  I appreciate the help and now I know where to look for my issues. Thank you

Comment: Ohhhh Kay, I see where I went wrong. Thank you Very much

Answer (score 0):

You could use a patttern with early exit and start frim the smallest value check to the greatest value.

The early exit returns a function and no more check is performed, because the function has ended with [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement.

For taking an integer value with [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), you should use a radix of `10`, because without and with leading zero the number is treated as octal number, which you do not want.

A last advice, please do not use name of build in functions or objects or reserved words as variable names. This could lead to not proper working code and to searching without reason.

```js
function calculateGrade(grade) {
    if (grade < 50){
        return "F";
    }
    if (grade < 60){
        return "E";
    }
    if (grade < 70) {
        return "D";
    }
    if (grade < 80) {
        return "C";
    }
    if (grade < 90) {
        return "B";
    }
    return "A";
}

var inputGrade = prompt("Enter a grade:"),
    grade = parseInt(inputGrade, 10),
    finalGrade = calculateGrade(grade);

console.log(finalGrade);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
function calculateGrade(grade) {
if (grade < 60){
    alert ("F");
}
else if (grade >= 60 && grade < 70){
    alert ("D");
}
else if(grade >= 70 && grade < 80);{
    alert ("C");
}
else if (grade >= 80 && grade < 90){
    alert ("B");
}
else if (grade >= 90){
    alert ("A");
}
}
var inputGrade = prompt("Enter a grade:");
var parsedInt = parseInt(inputGrade);
var finalGrade = calculateGrade(parsedInt);
alert(finalGrade);
```

Comment: [Please add some details or a little explanation about your code.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)